# Return info from instagram authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, instagram

Using the client side Instagram [authentication](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/), I'm able to obtain an access token allowing me to view user media:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=#####&redirect_uri=http..&response_type=token'
```

However, when I'm redirected, the user needs to re-input their username.  Is there a way to avoid this?  Example live [here](http://mkfreeman.github.io/collage/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways of accomplishing this using your site.

**Option One**

When user returns from Instagram with the access_token, substitute 'self' for {userid} in your current call.

Your current call:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1167507032/media/recent?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&callback={CALLBACK}`

Make call look like this:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&callback={CALLBACK}`

**Option Two**

When user returns from Instagram with access_token, make one additional call to Instagram API to obtain the current user's name/id like so:

```
var requestUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?' + ACCESS_TOKEN
var userId = ''
var userName = ''

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        url : requestUrl,
        success : function(response) {
            userId = response.data.id
            userName = response.data.username
        }
    });
```

Both of these should work, obviously with option two you would add a callback to the ajax call, I just wanted to show where in the response you would be getting the information you need.

Comment: For private users that get re-directed, there is currently no way to pass back the user-name from the authentication.  This means that the user has to re-enter it, which is a pain.

Comment: Check out the edits and let me know if this doesn't work